# Name of an Indian dish with stuffed whole potatoes

Tags: indian-cuisine, language, food-identification

I had a lovely Indian meal which I would like to find the name of. There were small whole potatoes with a little hole cut into them and filled with spices and (I think) some lamb mince. They were served in a spicy tomato sauce. Any idea what this dish is, or how I could figure out how to make it?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! This is a great question - I've just tweaked it slightly to remove the explicit recipe request. We try to avoid those, because they usually turn into popularity contests with everyone posting their favorite recipe. I'm sure people will still provide examples if they have them though!

Comment: @Carla Dolfing: Check whether its Potato Cutlet???

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are referring to is the [Kashmiri Dum Aloo](http://whatanindianrecipe.com/north-indian/stuffed-kashmiri-alu-dum-recipe.html), it's a vegetarian dish where potatoes are stuffed with a mix of *paneer* (cottage cheese) & cashew, and then cooked in a thick gravy. It's best enjoyed with any kind of Indian bread like *roti*, *naan*, *paratha*, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The Indian term for potato is aloo. I have seen this called stuffed aloo in the indian places around Oslo.

From what I understand, it has many variants, however most seem to involve hollowing out a potato, and adding a lamb mince curry sauce to the hole.

Answer (score 2):

Is Bharawan Aloo perhaps what you had in mind?  The recipe I found doesn't contain lamb, but I would imagine a dish like that probably comes in many variations.

[Bharawan Aloo](http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Bharawan-Aloo-_Stuffed-Potatoes_-Food_com-96907?columns=3&position=6/23)

Answer (score 1):

Arent you referring to [Dum aloo](http://arcsfoodparadise.com/2012/08/16/dum-aloo-baby-potatoes-in-a-spicy-gravy/),look below the picture comment it if the dish is which you searching for,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

potatoes are mostly used with meat in stews in Indian cuisine it must me Dum Aloo it doesn't contain any meat though.

Answer (score 1):

Aloo gujiya may be the dish you have in mind.Gujiyas have many categories like sweet gujiya having coconut and sugar as filling,veg gujjiya with green peas carrots and beetroot spicy fillings ,aloo gujiya with predominantly whole potato made spicy with pepper and chillies as a filling. Chicken gujiya, meat gujiya are also there.Made in a semicircular shape sealing the open ends after filling is done.[image]